# Finding total contributions of a user from GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to extract the below info for any user from GitHub.

[image: Example user contributions]

Is there a way/API exposed in [GitHub REST API](http://developer.github.com/v3/) where we can get this information directly?

Answer (score 33):

Answers for 2019, Use [GitHub API V4](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/contributionscollection/).

First go to GitHub to apply for a token: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line. step 7, scopes select only `read:user`

**cUrl**

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer token" -X POST -d '{"query":"query {\n  user(login: \"MeiK2333\") {\n    name\n    contributionsCollection {\n      contributionCalendar {\n        colors\n        totalContributions\n        weeks {\n          contributionDays {\n            color\n            contributionCount\n            date\n            weekday\n          }\n          firstDay\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}"}' https://api.github.com/graphql
```

**JavaScript**

```js
async function getContributions(token, username) {
    const headers = {
        'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`,
    }
    const body = {
        "query": `query {
            user(login: "${username}") {
              name
              contributionsCollection {
                contributionCalendar {
                  colors
                  totalContributions
                  weeks {
                    contributionDays {
                      color
                      contributionCount
                      date
                      weekday
                    }
                    firstDay
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }`
    }
    const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/graphql', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(body), headers: headers })
    const data = await response.json()
    return data
}

const data = await getContributions('token', 'MeiK2333')
console.log(data)
```

Comment: FYI: If you only want to know the total contribution of the authenticated user, `{"query": "query {viewer {contributionsCollection {contributionCalendar {totalContributions}}}}"}` should be enough.

Comment: Can you explain why you have used method POST, shouldn't it be GET?

Comment: @Maverick it is POST b/c graphQL is being used for this request. see this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162265/why-are-graphql-queries-post-requests-even-when-we-are-trying-to-fetch-data-and

Answer (score 15):

Yes, You can do this easily with the new graphql API

Check out the explorer: https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/

There you can see the contributions collection which is an edge of the user. You can get all of the information necessary to rebuild the calendar.

I've included a full example, and the explorer documentation can guide you even further.

Specifically to answer your question, the `query.user.contributionsCollection.contributionsCalendar.totalContributions`
is what you are looking for

Go ahead and copy/paste the following into the explorer and you will see my contribution history for the last year

```
query { 
  user(login: "qhenkart") {
    email
    createdAt
    contributionsCollection(from: "2019-09-28T23:05:23Z", to: "2020-09-28T23:05:23Z") {
      contributionCalendar {
        totalContributions
        weeks {
          contributionDays {
            weekday
            date 
            contributionCount 
            color
          }
        }
        months  {
          name
            year
            firstDay 
          totalWeeks 
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 15):

To load the svg with all contributions you can use this code in your html page

```
<img src="https://ghchart.rshah.org/username" alt="Name Your Github chart">
```

[image]

To customize color you can just do that

```
 <img src="https://ghchart.rshah.org/HEXCOLORCODE/username" alt="Name Your Github chart">
```

HEXCOLORCODE = **17A2B8**
[image]

Comment: Is there a way using this method to get the chart from another year?

Answer (score 7):

You can get the svg calendar from `https://github.com/users/<USER>/contributions` with `to` URL parameter like :

https://github.com/users/bertrandmartel/contributions?to=2016-12-31

You can use a basic xml parser to sum all the contributions from the svg.

An example with [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) for year 2016:

```bash
curl -s "https://github.com/users/bertrandmartel/contributions?to=2016-12-31" | \
     xmlstarlet sel -t -v "sum(//svg/g/g/rect/@data-count)"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [github events api](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/) for that:

### Example (node.js)

```js
const got = require('got')

async function getEvents(username) {
  const events = []
  let page = 1

  do {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/events?page=${page}`
    var { body } = await got(url, {
      json: true
    })
    page++
    events.push(...body)
  } while(!body.length)

  return events
}

(async () => {
  const events = await getEvents('handtrix')

  console.log('Overall Events', events.length)
  console.log('PullRequests', events.filter(event => event.type === 'PullRequestEvent').length)
  console.log('Forks', events.filter(event => event.type === 'ForkEvent').length)
  console.log('Issues', events.filter(event => event.type === 'IssuesEvent').length)
  console.log('Reviews', events.filter(event => event.type === 'PullRequestReviewEvent').length)
})()
```

### Example (javascript)

```js
async function getEvents(username) {
  const events = []
  let page = 1

  do {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/events?page=${page}`
    var body = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
    page++
    events.push(...body)
  } while(!body.length)

  return events
}

(async () => {
  const events = await getEvents('handtrix')

  console.log('Overall Events', events.length)
  console.log('PullRequests', events.filter(event => event.type === 'PullRequestEvent').length)
  console.log('Forks', events.filter(event => event.type === 'ForkEvent').length)
  console.log('Issues', events.filter(event => event.type === 'IssuesEvent').length)
  console.log('Reviews', events.filter(event => event.type === 'PullRequestReviewEvent').length)
})()
```

### Documentation

- https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/
- https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/got

Comment: When using this keep in mind that it only returns data from the last 90 days

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can see count of contributions in a timeframe as well as other individual contributor analytics within Code Climate’s Velocity git analytics, which you may request access to here: https://go.codeclimate.com/velocity-free-for-teams

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function to extract the contributions from the last year (client):

```
function getContributions(){
    const svgGraph = document.getElementsByClassName('js-calendar-graph')[0];
    const daysRects = svgGraph.getElementsByClassName('day');
    const days = [];

    for (let d of daysRects){
        days.push({
           date: d.getAttribute('data-date'),
           count: d.getAttribute('data-count')
        }); 
    }

    return days;    
}
```

I've also written a small node module which can 'extract' the contributions
 [@simonwep/github-contributions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@simonwep/github-contributions)

Maybe this will help you (even I'm 4 years to late)

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer a `npm` package, you can try this.
https://github.com/SammyRobensParadise/github-contributions-counter#readme

You can get all time contributions or contributions by each year.