# Why are GraphQL queries POST requests even when we are trying to fetch data and not update/submit new data?

Tags: graphql, postman

I am using Postman to fetch data from my server and when I use a REST call it is a GET request but when I use a GraphQL API call, it needs to be a POST request. Why is it so?

Comment: You can also use GET requests like `http://myapi/graphql?query={me{name}}` (Source: https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#get-request)
I think this depends on your API configuration.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The GraphQL spec is itself transport-agnostic, however the convention adopted by the community has been to utilize POST requests. As pointed out in the comments, some libraries support GET requests. However, when doing so, the query *has* to be sent as a URL query parameter since GET requests can't have bodies. This can be problematic with bigger queries since you can easily hit a [414 URI Too Long](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/414) status on certain servers.

The best practice is to always utilize POST requests with a `application/json` Content-Type.